# FastAPI - SQLAlchemy - Trouble returning most recent created child record with parent record

Tags: sqlalchemy, fastapi

I have tried reading the SQLAlchemy documents and trawled many articles here and other places with nothing working. I will admit I am no expert in SQLAlchemy and the solution maybe very simple.

I have a FastAPI running on a local Postgres database with two models for a small sample tracking system I want to implement. Simplified models are below:

```py
class Sample(Base):
    __tablename__ = "samples"

    id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(primary_key=True, index=True, autoincrement=True)
    : Mapped[str] = mapped_column(String(32), index=True)
    ...
    time_created: Mapped[datetime] = mapped_column(
        DateTime(timezone=True), server_default=func.now()
    )

    logs: Mapped[list["StationLog"]] = relationship(back_populates="sample")


class LocationLog(Base):
    __tablename__ = "locationlogs"
    
    id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(primary_key=True, index=True, autoincrement=True)
    ...
    time_created: Mapped[datetime] = mapped_column(
        DateTime(timezone=True), server_default=func.now()
    )
    sample_id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(ForeignKey("samples.id"))

    sample: Mapped["Sample"] = relationship(back_populates="logs")
```

For the endpoint my schema returns a list of the related LocationLog in the field logs as expected.
I want to limit this to only the latest `time_created`, but everything i have tried to do this has failed resulting in either an error or all locations being returned for each sample rather than the most recent.

From my research it points to using a SQLAlchemy query like this:

```py
subq = select(func.max(StationLog.time_created).label("max_created"), StationLog.sample_id).group_by(StationLog.sample_id).subquery()
query = select(Sample).join(subq, subq.c.sample_id == Sample.id)

db.scalars(query.order_by(Sample.id).offset(skip).limit(limit)).all()
```

However, this retrieves all of the related LocationLog records. I've also tried many other variations which either result in an error or just returning all of the related records.

Where am I going wrong? Thank in advance!

Answer (score 1):

This is kind of a weird problem but I think this will work.  Note that `distinct()` will generate a `DISTINCT ON` clause which is postgresql only.  You might be able to combine the sub and extra `LEFT OUTER JOIN` but I don't know how.  I think there are a few ways to do this.

```py
    # return the first distinct row for each sample id, ordering by time_created descending for each sample id.
    # I added the station log id in the ordering as a tie breaker to make the results deterministic.
    sub = select(
        StationLog.sample_id,
        StationLog.id,
        StationLog.time_created
    ).order_by(
        StationLog.sample_id,
        StationLog.time_created.desc(),
        StationLog.id
    ).distinct(
        StationLog.sample_id
    ).subquery()
    # we outer join to the subquery to get the "latest" station log id
    # then outer join again to fetch the full set of columns to
    # build a complete StationLog
    stmt = select(
        Sample,
        StationLog
    ).select_from(
        Sample
    ).outerjoin(
        sub,
        Sample.id == sub.c.sample_id
    ).outerjoin(
        StationLog,
        sub.c.id == StationLog.id)
    result = session.execute(stmt)
    # note that station_log will be None when there are no logs
    for (sample, station_log) in result:
        print (sample, station_log)
```

Comment: Thank Ian, unfortunately it had the same results with multiple logs being returned when only the most recent should be returned. It feels like this should be an easy problem and I wonder if FastAPI is doing something behind the scenes.

Comment: I'm fairly sure FastAPI is doing something as i compiled SQLalchemy code to SQL and ran it which did not have duplicates. Yet json from my api has two or more log records.

Comment: Trying turning `echo=True` on sqlalchemy engine and check log.

Comment: Just to be clear my answer didn't load a special list into the sample -- station log relationship, you can only get the single station log from iterating the result.  If you try to jsonify the sample alone it won't work.

Comment: So I’m assuming filtering in my crud doesn’t make any difference as the parent sample child logs are queried automatically somehow? Where is this behaviour documented? SQLalchemy, pydantic or fastapi?